# Need help getting ASUS USB-AC53 Nano (USB wifi adapter) working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, usb

Very much a noob but I am trying to get this wireless wi-fi adapter to work on an old computer my sister uses.  Old wireless wifi adapter was an ASUS but it died.  Any step by step help would be appreciated.  I have computer on a wired connection currently.  Thanks.

Comment: Start a terminal window with `Ctrl-Alt-T`, then type the command `journalctl --follow`. This will start displaying the systems logs, and continue until you type `Ctrl-C` in that window. Then plug in your adapter, and see what the logs say.

Comment: Here was the output

Answer (score 0):

It is supported by Linux but you need to install the driver and that the driver might have some issues with certain kernel versions.

Read this whole [thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/printthread.php?t=2362669&pp=10&page=1) till the end (including the [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362577) to the split thread) and follow his steps.

Provide the output of the following if you have issues (make sure you have the dongle connected):
`uname -a`
`lsusb`
`dmesg`
`ip a s`

Comment: It should be supported by Linux https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_USB-AC53_Nano

Comment: Ok - ran journalct1  --follow.  It appears the computer has identified the wifi nano.

Comment: Reviewed the threads and link but I'm too much a newby to understand what he did.  Any help on step by step basis would be appreciated.

Comment: Product: 802.11ac NIC
[67692.673204] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Realtek
[67692.673207] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 123456

Comment: @ReillyShaughnessy Sorry I disappear for a bit. I saw your thread below, glad to hear you read the links and got a step forward. Now, could you describe a bit more of how are you connecting and what do you mean by "connect with passkey"? Are you using network manager or command line? Something else?

Comment: I would still like to see the outputs of `dmesg | grep -nA 20 -i "usb\|wifi"` and `ip a s`

Comment: @ReillyShaughnessy any news?